# How could I export my Google Bookmarks in lists?

Tags: google, bookmarks, delicious

I use Google Bookmarks and all of my bookmarks are organized into lists.

When i hit export.. this is the file. and this is all i get:

```
<!DOCTYPE NETSCAPE-Bookmark-file-1>
<META HTTP-EQUIV="Content-Type" CONTENT="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
<TITLE>Bookmarks</TITLE>
<H1>Bookmarks</H1>
<DL><p>
</DL><p>
```

How could I export my Google Bookmarks ?

Comment: @downvoter downvote me after you can solve my problem

Comment: Are you sure you are not using lists?

Comment: @phwd what do you mean? of course i'm using lists

Comment: It's probably because your question leaves out a lot of information. You only now mention in the comments that you're using lists. Where is that in the body of the question?

Comment: @Eight it's weird to mention that I use lists since, well don't everyone uses list !?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you are using lists.

You cannot export lists.

As seen in the following example

[image: A list for waffles]

```
<!DOCTYPE NETSCAPE-Bookmark-file-1> 
<META HTTP-EQUIV="Content-Type" CONTENT="text/html; charset=UTF-8"> 
<TITLE>Bookmarks</TITLE> 
<H1>Bookmarks</H1> 
<DL><p> 
<DT><H3 ADD_DATE="1269610508467000">Unlabeled</H3> 
<DL><p> 
<DT><A HREF="http://users.powernet.co.uk/eton/kandr2/krx1.html" ADD_DATE="1288705980381398">The C Programming Language Answers To Exercises - Chapter 1</A> 
<DT><A HREF="http://books.google.ca/books?id=9DHsQ0CQNucC&amp;lpg=PA204&amp;ots=sNQz8F9iPn&amp;dq=wet+scrubber+design&amp;pg=PA204#v=onepage&amp;q=wet%20scrubber%20design&amp;f=false" ADD_DATE="1269610508467000">Air pollution control engineering</A> 
</DL><p> 
</DL><p>
```

Comment: do you mean you don't use lists? how do you organise your bookmarks then?

Answer (score 2):

Works for me. This is what I did:

1. Go to https://www.google.com/bookmarks/
2. Select "All" so that all bookmarks are checked
3. Click "Export bookmarks" in the left column
4. Download HTML file with bookmark data

Comment: that's exactly what i did. but it'sn't working

Comment: No need to select all. Export bookmarks seems to export all bookmarks.